# How to emit to particular clients which are property names of javascript object

Tags: javascript, node.js, object, for-loop, socket.io

I've got an object `var usernames = {};`
After login client's emitting addUser to server

```
socket.on('addUser', function(data) { 
    if (usernames[data] == undefined) { 
        socket.username = data;
        username = socket.username;
        usernames[username] = socket.id;
    }
}
```

I'm adding each client to my object and I want to emit to that clients message. I'm doing something like this:

```
 socket.on('disconnect', function() {  
        dbConnection.query('DELETE FROM active_users WHERE login="' + username + '" AND socket_id="' + socketId + '"');
        delete usernames[socket.username];
        delete io.sockets.sockets[username];
        socket.leave(socket.room);                 

        for (var prop in usernames) {
            usernames[prop].emit('updateChat', usernames[prop] + ' has left the room');  
        }
    });
```

It doesn't work. I want achieve something like this --> http://michaelheap.com/sending-messages-to-certain-clients-with-socket-io/ but in these example author uses array. I have to use object, any ideas?

client

```
socket.on('updateChat', function(data) { 
    $('<p>' + data + '</p>').appendTo($('#conversation'));   
});
```

Getting error

> TypeError: Object fI7dpiwjMzkD0tN69C6c has no method 'emit'
>       at Socket. (C:\Users\User\app\server.js:135:17)
>       at Socket.EventEmitter.emit [as $emit] (events.js:95:17)
>       at Socket.onDisconnect (C:\Users\User\app\node_modules\socket.io\lib\sock et.js:153:10)
>       at SocketNamespace.handleDisconnect (C:\Users\User\app\node_modules\socke t.io\lib\namespace.js:229:46)
>       at Manager.onClientDisconnect (C:\Users\User\app\node_modules\socket.io\l ib\manager.js:501:29)
>       at WebSocket.Transport.end (C:\Users\User\app\node_modules\socket.io\lib\ transport.js:467:20)
>       at WebSocket.Transport.onSocketEnd (C:\Users\User\app\node_modules\socket .io\lib\transport.js:147:8)
>       at Socket.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:117:20)
>       at _stream_readable.js:920:16
>       at process._tickCallback (node.js:415:13) DEBUG: Program node server.js exited with code 8

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need to do is:

```
 for (var prop in usernames) {
     usernames[prop].emit('updateChat', usernames[prop] + ' has left the room');
 }
```

To emit the username.

Comment: I updated my code, now you can see more. When I disconnect I get an error "Object ...(here is socket.id) has no method 'emit'"

Comment: Does every single property of username have an emit method??

Comment: None has. Look at the code, I upadated again. Each client shoud get a message that particular user has left the room. Nobody gets, nothing happens

Comment: Do you see anything in the console?

Comment: TypeError: Object fI7dpiwjMzkD0tN69C6c has no method 'emit'
    at Socket.<anonymous> (C:\Users\User\app\server.js:135:17)
    at Socket.EventEmitter.emit [as $emit] (events.js:95:17)
    at Socket.onDisconnect

Comment: This code would tell each user that they left the room, except id's themselves have no emit method which is why you're getting a server error.

Answer (score 0):

Last line of the [socket.io wiki](https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io/wiki/How-do-I-send-a-response-to-all-clients-except-sender%3F)

**Update 1**

```
socket.on('addUser', function(data) { 
    if (usernames[data] == undefined) { 
        socket.username = data;
        username = socket.username;
        usernames[username] = socket.id;
    }
}
```

should be:

```
socket.on('addUser', function(data) { 
    if (usernames[data] == undefined) { 
        socket.set("username", data);
        //use getters and setters
        username = data;
        usernames[username] = socket.id;
    }
}
```

Which will solve the undefined username issue.

**Update 2**

```
socket.on('disconnect', function() {  
    dbConnection.query('DELETE FROM active_users WHERE login="' + username + '" AND socket_id="' + socketId + '"');
    var un=socket.username;
    delete usernames[socket.username];
    delete io.sockets.sockets[username];
    socket.leave(socket.room); 
    for(var prop in usernames)
        if(io.sockets.socket(usernames[prop]).emit)
            io.sockets.socket(usernames[prop]).emit('updateChat', un + ' has left the room');
});
```

from the original answer should be modified to:

```
socket.on('disconnect', function() {  
    var un=socket.get('username');
    //use the getter appropriately

    dbConnection.query('DELETE FROM active_users WHERE login="' + un + '" AND socket_id="' + usernames[un] + '"');

    delete usernames[un];
    socket.leave(socket.room);
    //Leave before you remove your own connection

    delete io.sockets.sockets[usernames[un]];

    for(var prop in usernames)
        if(io.sockets.sockets[usernames[prop]].emit)
            io.sockets.sockets[usernames[prop]].emit('updateChat', un + ' has left the room');
});
```

Emits to everyone in `usernames`.

Although life would be much easier if you just used:

```
socket.broadcast.emit('updateChat', un + " has left the room.");
```

Comment: Then each client gets "undefined has left the room" twice

Comment: then `socket.username` is undefined. I think you have a problem upstream.

Comment: try `console.log(data)` in your serverside code registering the user.

Comment: There is no problem with username when I use my username variable instead (socket.username = data; username = socket.username;) But it is still emitting as many messages to each client as there are added clients. So when I have 3 users, and one has left, other two get message "... has left the room" thrice

Comment: TypeError: undefined is not a function
    at Client.get (C:\Users\User\app\node_modules\socket.io\lib\stores\memory
.js:86:3)
    at Socket.get (C:\Users\User\app\node_modules\socket.io\lib\socket.js:258
:14)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (C:\Users\User\app\server.js:115:19)
    at Socket.EventEmitter.emit [as $emit] (events.js:95:17)
    at Socket.onDisconnect (C:\Users\User\app\node_modules\socket.io\lib\sock
et.js:153:10)
    at SocketNamespace.handleDisconnect (C:\Users\User\app\node_modules\socke
t.io\lib\namespace.js:229:46)
    at Manager.onClientDisconnect

Comment: Thanks Jason but I get this error when I use solution with for loop. When I use broadcast, each client still gets to much message, should gets only one..

Comment: you used broadcast without the `for` loop and got more than one message?

Comment: socket.on('disconnect', function() {  
        dbConnection.query('DELETE FROM active_users WHERE login="' + username + '" AND socket_id="' + socketId + '"');
        delete usernames[socket.username];
        delete io.sockets.sockets[username];
        socket.leave(socket.room);                
 socket.broadcast.to(socket.room).emit('updateChat', username + ' has left the room');  
         });

Comment: that looks my disconnect function now and each client gets more than one message

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44967/discussion-between-jason-nichols-and-elevenminutes)